# C pipe fork fd question - simple xv6 pingpong question

Tags: c, xv6

C newbie here. I am trying to write a simple program in xv6 that utilizes pipes, forks, and file descriptors.

```c
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int p[2];  // file descriptors for pipe
    char recv_buf[5];

    pipe(p);

    if (fork() == 0) {  // child
        read(p[0], recv_buf, 5);
        printf("%d: received %s\n", getpid(), recv_buf);
        close(p[0]);

        write(p[1], "pong", 5);
        close(p[1]);

    } else {  // parent
        write(p[1], "ping", 5);
        close(p[1]);

        read(p[0], recv_buf, 5);
        printf("%d: received %s\n", getpid(), recv_buf);
        close(p[0]);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

I thought that the program would succeed in printing

```
$ ./pingpong
$ "3: received ping" 
$ "4: received pong"
```

to the terminal output.

Instead the output comes out as:

```
$ ./pingpong
$ "3: received ping"
```

Can anyone explain what's happening here?  I thought that each process had its own file descriptor copy, and that read/write would hang the parent process until there is output on the other end of the pipe.  So why is it that that the child process is not receiving the "pong" call?

Note that if I add a wait(0) in the parent, the problem goes away.

```c
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int p[2];  // file descriptors for pipe
    char recv_buf[5];

    pipe(p);

    if (fork() == 0) {  // child
        read(p[0], recv_buf, 5);
        printf("%d: received %s\n", getpid(), recv_buf);
        close(p[0]);

        write(p[1], "pong", 5);
        close(p[1]);

    } else {  // parent
        write(p[1], "ping", 5);
        wait(0); // this fixes the problem.  but why?
        close(p[1]);

        read(p[0], recv_buf, 5);
        printf("%d: received %s\n", getpid(), recv_buf);
        close(p[0]);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

```
$ ./pingpong
$ "3: received ping" 
$ "4: received pong"
```

Can anyone explain why the wait(0) causes the program to succeed?

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured out the answer shortly after typing this.

The program with the first program is that inside the parent block I am writing to the output file descriptor, then reading from the input file descriptor immediately after, which means the parent process doesn't hang.

The result is that the parent process exits before the child process is able to make any read/writes.

```c
    if (fork() == 0) {  // child process never reached
        read(p[0], recv_buf, 5);
        printf("%d: received %s\n", getpid(), recv_buf);
        close(p[0]);

        write(p[1], "pong", 5);
        close(p[1]);

    } else {  // parent
        write(p[1], "ping", 5); // write to output fd
        close(p[1]); // close output fd

        read(p[0], recv_buf, 5); // read "ping" from input fd
        printf("%d: received %s\n", getpid(), recv_buf); // print "ping"
        close(p[0]); // close input fd
    }
    exit(0); // parent process exists immediately
```

wait(0) fixes this by allow the child process to read/write prior to the parent reaching the read block

Comment: I have to say, it seems like this isn't a great way to use pipe(). You've got a consumer-producer problem where the producer can consume its own product because both processes are using the same pipe. It might be better to have used two pipes going in opposite ways to avoid this kind of issue.

Comment: @akatz

Thanks for the comment.  That makes a lot of sense.

So in effect what I should do is make two sets of file descriptor arrays, then run pipe() on each. Then perform read-write on separate pipes.